# Is there an equivalent of python `dir` for haskell ghci?

Tags: haskell, ghci

Is there an equivalent of python `dir` for haskell `ghci`?

In the python interpreter, `dir` shows the defined symbols. I would like to use something similar also in Haskell, in order to explore the functions provided by the imported modules.

```
me@mine$ python
>>> from pickle import *
>>> dir()
['APPEND', 'APPENDS', 'BINFLOAT', 'BINGET', 'BININT', 'BININT1', 'BININT2', 'BINPERSID', 'BINPUT', 'BINSTRING', 'BINUNICODE', 'BUILD', 'DICT', 'DUP', 'EMPTY_DICT', 'EMPTY_LIST', 'EMPTY_TUPLE', 'EXT1', 'EXT2', 'EXT4', 'FALSE', 'FLOAT', 'GET', 'GLOBAL', 'HIGHEST_PROTOCOL', 'INST', 'INT', 'LIST', 'LONG', 'LONG1', 'LONG4', 'LONG_BINGET', 'LONG_BINPUT', 'MARK', 'NEWFALSE', 'NEWOBJ', 'NEWTRUE', 'NONE', 'OBJ', 'PERSID', 'POP', 'POP_MARK', 'PROTO', 'PUT', 'PickleError', 'Pickler', 'PicklingError', 'REDUCE', 'SETITEM', 'SETITEMS', 'SHORT_BINSTRING', 'STOP', 'STRING', 'TRUE', 'TUPLE', 'TUPLE1', 'TUPLE2', 'TUPLE3', 'UNICODE', 'Unpickler', 'UnpicklingError', '__builtins__', '__doc__', '__name__', '__package__', 'dump', 'dumps', 'load', 'loads']
```

Comment: Closest thing I know of is `:browse` for showing the bindings exported by a single module.

Comment: could be a valid answer

Comment: I wouldn't be surprised if the functionality to list all local symbols doesn't exist in GHCi since you can do `:browse Prelude`, `:browse <MyModule/Main>`, and `:browse <Library>` to get all the information you need.  I'd just stick to that.  It's a bit different from the `dir()` function in that `dir()` is a proper function which returns a list of strings that you can manipulate.

Comment: Note that `:browse` also works without arguments, showing all values in scope

Comment: @GabrielGonzalez if this is true, `:browse` is the closest thing to `dir` in `ghci`. Actually after your answers i used it to accomplish what i needed. The perfect answer would integrate your comments and @YellPika answer mentioning `:browse`, tab completion, and the difference with `dir()` mentioned by @bheklilr

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This summarizes the answers in the comments like you suggested.

You can use the `:browse` command without arguments in `ghci` to view all values imported from the most recently imported module.  If you call it when you enter `ghci` it will output all values imported by the `Prelude`.  You can also use `:browse <ModuleName>` to browse a module that you have not yet imported.

This, however, does not work for values that you defined yourself in `ghci`.  To access those, use tab completion, like `YellPika` suggested.

Comment: i think this summarises well, i wrote the @YellPika example esplicitely

Answer (score 3):

AFAIK, there is no *direct* equivalent of `dir` in Haskell. If you just want to browse definitions in GHCI, then all you need to do is hit tab.

Ex:

```
ghci> [tab]
Display all 470 possibilities? (y or n) [y]
{spits everything that's currently in scope}

ghci> Prelude.[tab]
Display all 235 possibilities? (y or n) [y]
{spits out everything in the Prelude namespace}
```